# How to tune a lagging linux server?

Tags: linux, centos7

A server is lagging a lot while viewing logs, even when I'm using `less` comman to view the logs. Yes, I agree the log sizes are worth 400MB (after splitting).

One of the issues I think could be the lack of space in server. There is only 15% disk space remaining on server. But talking to my senior colleagues, they laughed off when I said, "adding space could solve the freezing issue of server". So, I guess I'm wrong here.

There seems to be enough RAM as well.

Now, I wonder why the server is lagging that much. We access the server via anydesk.

I am not asking you guys to tell me "Why", but at least tell me "how can I find what is the bottleneck of that server?".

I'll be glad with anything, even URLs to read. I know we're using centos 7 nearing its EOL, but I don't think that's something we  can change within a week or even a month.

Comment: `We access the server via anydesk` that's certainly not helping. But jokes aside, you need to provide a lot more details for anybody to start analyzing. Hardware specs, usage statistics (RAM, CPU, I/O etc.)

Comment: I mean you can tell me how to analyze those stuffs and I'd do it myself.

Comment: That's not something we can tell you; it's a process you have to learn. In general it includes looking at logs and performance metrics, to attempt to figure out what's the problem. Where to start looking depends on what kind of application you're running, and knowledge of that application.

Comment: You can tell me what's tellable.

Comment: I wrote [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/698921/37681) a long time ago to help with the vague statement that *"performance tuning is as much a black art as it is a science"*

Comment: got it. First monitor, second monitor, thirdly monitor, then change a bit!

Comment: And then confirm in your monitoring if the change had the desired result, then revert or keep.